# telnet command not listening asterisk manager events

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am trying to catch some log of events in asterisk manager (AMI) with command **telnet 0.0.0.0 5038**, like in the image below, but nothing appears.

```
[root@localhost vagrant]# telnet 0.0.0.0 5038
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.0.0.0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Asterisk Call Manager/1.3
```

In Asterisk CLI the connection of manager appears (image below).

```
    [root@localhost vagrant]# asterisk -vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvr
    Asterisk 11.11.0, Copyright (C) 1999 - 2013 Digium, Inc. and others.
    Created by Mark Spencer 
    Asterisk comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; type 'core show warranty' for details.
    This is free software, with components licensed under the GNU General Public
    License version 2 and other licenses; you are welcome to redistribute it under
    certain conditions. Type 'core show license' for details.
    =========================================================================
    Connected to Asterisk 11.11.0 currently running on localhost (pid = 3896)
    localhost*CLI> 
      == Manager 'teste' logged on from 192.168.56.101
      == Manager 'teste' logged on from 192.168.56.101
      == Manager 'teste' logged off from 192.168.56.101
      == Manager 'teste' logged off from 192.168.56.101
```

My netstat:

```
  

    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5038                0.0.0.0:*                   OUÇA       3896/asterisk
```

### Using:

- CentOS release 6.6
- Asterisk 11.11
- This is manager.conf:

  ```
       [general]
      enabled=yes
      webenabled=yes
      port=5038
      bindaddr=0.0.0.0
      debug=on
      authlimit=500000

      [teste]
      secret=test123
      read=all,system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config
      write=all,system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,config
      writetimeout=9999
      displayconnects=yes
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My foult :/ I just forget to do the login into telnet.

Type into telnet:

```
action:login
username:teste
secret:teste123
```

...and good to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 5038
```

Here,
telnet : command for telnet application
127.0.0.1 : host for the asterisk
5038 : default ami port
Then you can see the ami commandline interface and version of asterisk installed..

Type the following to login to you ami manager session

```
Action: login
Username:amiuname
Password: amilwd
```

**Here amiuname and amipwd were sey in the manager.conf**